# How to center this image inside div container?

Tags: html, containers, center

Here is the code: jsfiddle.net/Trebal/8kUyx/2

The image shall be vertically centered.

Does someone maybe know how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT FOR VERTICAL:

HTML Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8kUyx/21/

Given that your `.topbar` is a set height at the image is a set height, you can use `padding-top: 6.5px` to get the image horizontally centered.

CSS Solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8kUyx/35/

Using `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` you can vertically align the `.image`.

Comment: Horizontally, not vertically.

Comment: Dang, you beat me to the punch!

Comment: The image is centered horizontally (which is left to right)

Comment: Sorry, I confused horizontally and vertically. Then I meant vertically. Again, sorry.

Comment: Why downvote? The asker asked for horizontally originally. Working on a fix now.

Comment: Thanks. So, I have to use HTML or is there also a CSS variant?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.topbar {
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
background: #04091f;
line-height: 35px;
z-index: 5;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;`
}
```

Comment: Vertically, not horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-right:auto and margin-left:auto and get rid of the float:left.

```
.image {
   background: url(http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080120194739/wowwiki/images/a/a7/Icon-wowinsider-22x22.png) no-repeat;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/8kUyx/8/

You should modify your `.image` class like that:

```
.image {
    background: url(http://img2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20080120194739/wowwiki/images/a/a7/Icon-wowinsider-22x22.png) no-repeat;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I know how to do this, I mean centered vertically!

Comment: maybe you should try add `vertical-align: middle` to your parent div css rule?